# AR.Drone functions usages in Android

Tags: java, android, ar.drone, drone.io

Can someone clarify how to make a drone fly using the DroneProxy API class?
I'm using AR.Drone 2.0.

What I want to make is an indoor independent flying application. I want to input coordinates like a 2 meters left, then 3 meters right, turn right, then 10 meter to front, turn left, and few meters to front.

I tried to do this via methods below, but I cannot understand why it flies just for a few centimeters by one value input.

```
/**
 * Sends ArDrone the gaz value. Makes drone to move up or down
 *
 * @param value - value between -1 and 1.
 */
public void setGaz(final float value) {
    droneProxy.setControlValue(CONTROL_SET_GAZ, value);
}

/**
 * Sends ArDrone the Roll value. Makes drone to move left or right
 *
 * @param value - value between -1 and 1.
 */
public void setRoll(final float value) {
    droneProxy.setControlValue(CONTROL_SET_ROLL, value);
}

/**
 * Sends ArDrone the Pitch value. Makes drone to move forward or backward
 *
 * @param value - value between -1 and 1.
 */
public void setPitch(final float value) {
    droneProxy.setControlValue(CONTROL_SET_PITCH, value);
}

/**
 * Sends ArDrone the gaz value. Makes drone to turn left or right
 *
 * @param value - value between -1 and 1.
 */
public void setYaw(final float value) {
    droneProxy.setControlValue(CONTROL_SET_YAW, value);
}
```

Comment: these methods look pretty clear. you tell it how much you want in roll, pitch, yaw, gaz, and it does that.

Comment: now, if you want it to be autonomous, or to be able to move to a specific position, you need a feedback loop, i.e. reading from sensors to interprete and translate into adjustements to the commands. but without the complete api, it is hard to imagine how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, use methods instead:

```
            droneControlService.moveDown(0);
            droneControlService.moveUp(0);
            droneControlService.turnRight(0);
            droneControlService.turnLeft(0);
            droneControlService.moveForward(0);
            droneControlService.moveBackward(0);
```